# request.getParameter("param") doesn't return value, when the param=xyz%

Tags: java, servlets

I'm passing one parameter `param` from `jsp` to `servlet` having a value like `%xyz`.

When I'm trying to get the value in servlet by `request.getParameter("param")`  I'm not getting any value.

Instead it is coming as blank (Not even Null).

Can, anyone please explain the reason.

Comment: How is the URL that you are accessing?

Comment: http://localhost:8680/tri2v2/jsp/migration/MigrationDataServlet?instanceName=HLR12TST&applicationName=Application%20Object%20Library&objectType=CONCURRENT_PROGRAM_NAME&cmd=getObjectName&objectName=&entityName=PROGRAM&objectNameFilter=FND%

Above is the URL generated after submitting the form in JSP

Answer (score 7):

The `%` is a special character in uri. You have to encode the `%` value using uri encoding.
In your case the `%` should be encoded as `%25`